# How can I get firefox to set style attributes using style['attribute-name'] =?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

In this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9cb2/) Chrome sets the background red, firefox and IE do not.

Trying:

```
document.getElementById("firefoxDiv").style['backgroundColor'] = "Red";
```

and

```
document.getElementById("firefoxDiv").style['background-color'] = "Red";
```

I would much rather be able to use the same syntax used in external CSS
`background-color` vs inline using javascript `.style.backgroundColor =`

Thanks for your help!

*Note:* **NO** jQuery please.

Comment: @ZoltanToth I'm confused as to if you've read the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.style.setProperty(propertyName, value [, priority])`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration-setProperty) instead of an expando property.

Example:

```
document.getElementById("firefoxDiv").style.setProperty('background-color', 'red');
```